# Hibernate batching unexpected behavior

Tags: hibernate, batch-file

I have a simple example entity A which has an id and a version field. Id generation strategy is set to TABLE. Properties `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` and `hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data` are set to `20` and `true`.

I am trying to do a batch insert of the entity A with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            A a = new A();
            a.persist();
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
        }
```

Looking at MySQL logs, this results in 500 separate `insert into a (version, id) values (0, X)` statements, whereas I was expecting something like `insert into a (version, id) values (0, 1), (0, 2),...(0, 20)` repeated 25 times.

Setting `hibernate.jdbc` log level to debug shows:

> `org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 20`
>    `org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - no batched statements to execute`

Using Hibernate 3.6.8, MySQL 5.5.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - It seems that hibernate does not group single insert statements into ones that insert multiple rows. With hibernate batching enabled, MySQL will do this if *rewriteBatchedStatements* JDBC driver setting is set to *true*.